# accuracy of sinl and cosl function in c++

Tags: c++, precision, floating-accuracy

I want an accuracy of about `0.000001`.

```
typedef struct p {

    long double x;
    long double y;

}point;

point rotate_point(long double cx,long double cy,long double angle,point p) //pivot then angle then point to rotate
{ // cout<<"\ncx="<<cx<<"cy="<<cy<<"x="<<p.x<<"y="<<p.y;
    angle=(angle/100)*pi*2;


  // translate point back to origin:
  p.x -= cx;
  p.y -= cy;
  cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(20);

  // rotate point
  long double xnew = p.x * cosl(-angle) - p.y * sinl(-angle);
  long double ynew = p.x * sinl(-angle) + p.y * cosl(-angle);

  // translate point back:
  p.x = xnew + cx;
  p.y = ynew + cy;
   cout<<"x="<<p.x<<"y="<<p.y;
  return p;
}
```

Here is the code segment which I am using I am using the function `rotate_point` to rotate a point about a given pivot, here `cx`, `cy` are the pivots, `point` is the point to rotate in clockwise direction, `angle` is the angle passed in degrees (I cant pass it in radians assume that). My problem is when I call the function with values `rotate_point(50,50,25, p)`
where `p.x=50 p.y=100` then expected output is `x=100 y=50`.

I am getting `x=99.99999000666841262458 y=49.96838777042233631365`, `x` is ok but `y` is not in desired accuracy range.

Comment: Don't the [rules](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/terms/) say "don't cheat" to solve [the problem](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problem/1254819954559001/)?!

Comment: What is `angle=(angle/100)*pi*2;` supposed to do? It is not degrees to radians conversion, but similar. What is `pi`? Perhaps you have `pi = 3.142` or other crass value. Use the value defined in the math library header.

Comment: pi is #define pi (22/7) and actually its degree to radian conversion
(angle/100)*pi*(360/180)

Comment: HaHaha I almost suggested that and could not believe it could be so bad. Use a good value of PI if you want precision FFS.

Comment: suggest a way to use good value of pi?

Comment: I did. Read the comments.

Comment: Why are you `typedef`ing the struct?

Comment: there is no variable defined as PI in math.h

Comment: @UnholySheep so that i dont need to type struct point x everytime i declare a point , i can use point x directly

Comment: **Read thru the `math.h` header**. In C it is `M_PI` but you also need `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES`. However that is C and the C tag has been removed.

Comment: Thank you , you solved my problem @ Weather Vale i used M_PI

Comment: @sakshamjain you don't need to do that in C++ either. `typedef struct` is a C construct, it's unnecessary in C++

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks for pointing out i didnt know that difference between C++ and C

Comment: While 22/7 is a rough approximation to pi in the real world, in programming its a bad approximation: its value is 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not use the value

```
pi = 22 / 7
```

if you want accuracy. Please use

```
M_PI
```

which is defined in `math.h`. In MSVC you also need

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
```

to make the following values available.

```
#define M_E        2.71828182845904523536   // e
#define M_LOG2E    1.44269504088896340736   // log2(e)
#define M_LOG10E   0.434294481903251827651  // log10(e)
#define M_LN2      0.693147180559945309417  // ln(2)
#define M_LN10     2.30258509299404568402   // ln(10)
#define M_PI       3.14159265358979323846   // pi
#define M_PI_2     1.57079632679489661923   // pi/2
#define M_PI_4     0.785398163397448309616  // pi/4
#define M_1_PI     0.318309886183790671538  // 1/pi
#define M_2_PI     0.636619772367581343076  // 2/pi
#define M_2_SQRTPI 1.12837916709551257390   // 2/sqrt(pi)
#define M_SQRT2    1.41421356237309504880   // sqrt(2)
#define M_SQRT1_2  0.707106781186547524401  // 1/sqrt(2)
```